# How to give feedback for an Apple app not listed on the Product Feedback page?

Tags: macos, ios, notes.app

For example, Notes app is not listed on the [Apple Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) page. And I want to suggest adding a Horizontal Line, like HTML `<hr/>` to Notes app.

Comment: Do you have a twitter account? If yes, then ask, _How to request a new feature for an Apple app not listed on the Apple Product Feedback page?_, at https://twitter.com/AppleSupport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After suggestion from @user3439894, I had tweeted Apple Support and here is their answer:

> We love feedback. If you don’t see the Apple app you wish to leave feedback for, you can leave feedback by choosing the ***device you are using*** here: http://apple.co/Feedback

So, following that, I had posted the feedback using one of my devices as a channel, explaining in notes why am I using the device channel, and also listing all the OSs that I mean this feature request for.

Comment: What was the FR ?

Comment: Add a Horizontal Line, like HTML <hr />  to Notes app. I had suggested to add it just above Table in the Format menu in macOS. I had suggested to add it High Sierra and on, and iOS 13 and on. I would be super surprised if they would :)